# jquery autocomplete: several elements selected, how to not showing the selected elements in the drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have implemented a jquery autocomplete input that shows an drop-down list.

I'm using that field to choose several elements, so when I select an element and press enter the input is emptied and I can select another one.

My doubt: what can I do to not showing in the drop-down list the elements that has been selected?

This is my js code:

```
  jQuery("#user_autocomplete")
  .autocomplete('autocompleteUser', jQuery.extend({}, {
    dataType: 'json',
    parse: function(data) {

      var parsed = [];
      for (key in data) {

    parsed[parsed.length] = { data: [ data[key], key ], value: data[key], result: data[key] };
      }

      return parsed;

      }
  } ))
  .result(function(event, data) {
   $('#field_users').append('<div class="user_choosen" id=' + data[1] + '>' + data[0] +'<a class="link_delete_user" href="#" onclick="javascript:deleteUser(' + data[1] +')">Delete</a></div>'); 
    $('#user_autocomplete').val(''); 

  });
```

Regards

Javi

Comment: Why would you want to hide the selection from your users?

Comment: Looks like you will need a custom widget-ized autocomplete. In the item parsing section of it, you'd select not tho add them to the list.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to edit the source attribute of the autocomplete. After you have performed your fetch and received your JSON data, remove the elements that are already in the `div.user_chosen`. You can edit the options of the autocomplete at any time. You'll want to edit the `source` option.

Answer (score 0):

In your parse function, filter out those already-selected elements and do not add them into the parsed[] array.